# Discord py Receives hex code and prints it in embed color

Tags: python, discord.py

I want to input a hex color code with a command and express it as an embed color.

This code

```
async def parameter(self, interaction: Interaction, hexc: str) -> None:

    embed = discord.Embed(title= f"TEST", description="Test2", color=hex(hexc)

    await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed)
```

The problem is that this code outputs this error.

```
discord.app_commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command 'color' raised an exception: 
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Comment: Can you try changing the following like this:
`embed = discord.Embed(title= f"TEST", description="Test2", color=hex(int(hexc))`

Comment: I tried to change it, but I get this error:

`ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'ff0000'`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`int()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#int) with `base` 16. 16, because the hexadecimal system has 16 digits (0-9 and A-F):

```py
hex_int = int(hexc, base=16)
```

So the end result looks like this (I assume that you use the slash command in a cog):

```py
@app_commands.command()
async def parameter(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, hexc: str):
    # remove '#' if the format is like '#000000'
    hexc = hexc.strip("#")
        
    # convert hex string to hex integer
    hex_int = int(hexc, base=16)

    embed = discord.Embed(title=f"TEST", description="Test2", colour=hex_int)
    await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed)
```

`hexc` could have the following formats:

- `000000`
- `0x000000`
- `#000000` -> `hexc = hexc.strip("#")`